# psql: how to turn off context messages at raise notice

Tags: postgresql, psql

If I use raise notice, I get context messages at each execution.  Can I turn them 
off and just get the NOTICE?

```
NOTICE:  d = [2,1] ,tn: (1,2,"{NULL,NULL}","{{-1,4},{-1,-1}}",1)
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT aPt( vl , tn_id, color )  from tnodes where tnode_id = tn_id"
PL/pgSQL function "apt" line 42 at PERFORM
SQL statement "select  aPt(vl, tn.chldrn[d[1]][d[2]], color) from tnodes where tnode_id = tn_id"
PL/pgSQL function "apt" line 46 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT aPt('{0.5,1}',itVar,1)"
PL/pgSQL function "bi" line 16 at PERFORM
```

I'm using postgres 9.1.14,
Thanks.

Comment: I think it's controlled by [log_error_verbosity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ERROR-VERBOSITY) Try `set log_error_verbosity=DEFAULT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion applies to the contents of the log file.  For `psql`, the equivalent is `\set VERBOSITY terse`.

Comment: Of note, `VERBOSITY` is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution :**
As write – dezso Feb 17 '15 at 14:56, using \set VERBOSITYE 'terse' is the right way.

I've to add this option in my scripts using psql :

```
psql --dbname=DB_production --VERBOSITY=terse
```

But, I can't understand why on others instances, servers, environments, I haven't to do this.

Comment: What does is the postgresql.conf `log_error_verbosity` value in those other environments?